# Problema al crear imagen con Faker

Tags: laravel

Cree un factory en el cual necesito almacenar una imagen.

El factory es:

```
$factory->define(\App\FinDra\Entities\Surface\SurfaceModel::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'surface' => str_random(5),
        'color' => '#6c757d',
        'image_code' => $faker->image('public/storage/surfaces')
    ];
});
```

y al ejecutar php artisan migrate:refresh --seed me tira el error:

> Cannot write to directory "public/storage/surfaces"

A la carpeta storage le di los permisos que le doy siempre a todos los proyectos y esto funciona

1. chmod -R 775 storage (probe con 777 tambien)
2. chown -R juan:www-data  storage

y luego hago:

> php artisan storage:link

y con todo esto me dice que no se puede escribir en el directorio que quiero guardar la imagen.

Actualización:

Si creo manualmente la carpeta surfaces, crea sin problema la imagen la imagen con el faker, si no existe la carpeta tira error (anteriormente creaba automaticamente)

Comment: Sin duda es un problema de permisos, quizás el error se genera es por la ruta, puedes ver en el log de laravel si te da la ruta completa del error? o intenta dando la ruta completa en la linea $faker->image('public/storage/surfaces')

Comment: intentanaste con `mkdir -p  public/storage/surfaces & chmod +rw  public/storage/surfaces` porque parese que la carpeta no exisitiera en la ruta o no tienes los permisos requeridos

Answer (score 0):

```
\Faker\Provider\Image::image(storage_path().'\app\public\users',200,200,'people',false)
```

Esta seria una posible solución a tus problemas al crear imagenes con faker.
**storage_path()** tomaria la ruta del proyecto exclusivamente en la carpeta **storage** que genera laravel al ser creado.